# How can I improve the speed of Sublime Text 3 at handling huge files

Tags: sublimetext3

I am working on huge text files in the range of 600MB+ using Sublime Text 3. Vim and other editors are too cumbersome to use with unicode text. I am trying to find ways to increase resources reserved for Sublime under windows (RAM, CPU time, ... etc) but got no where. Any help on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime wasn't created to work with large files.

You have to configure lightweight editor and start using it.

Vim is the best candidate.

If you only need to search through that file, use less implementation for windows.